# Can I extend slider thumb beyond the track

Tags: flex4, flash-builder, flashcatalyst

Programming newbie here,

I am writing a trombone app in Flex and I want the slide of the trombone to act as an HSlider.  I have all the components  and skins assigned, but my slider only moves about 20 pixels in the wrong direction.  I figured that the thumb component is actually longer than the track.  This results in the thumb bumping up against the border of the track and not allowing it to move where I want it to go.

I guess I want to register a point on the thumb component to act as the thumb instead of the whole image.  Is that possible?

I wanted to post pictures, but I don't have a high enough reputation yet.

Thanks,

JMartin

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with Flex 4, with a proper skin implementation, this should not be too difficult.

1. Define a custom skin for your
   slider,
2. Once in the skin, switch to
   design view
3. Move your "cursor" as
   expected.

My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Flash Catalyst in order to build up your HSlider. Then Export the Slider to Flash Builder.